# How to set a variable with an environment variable read from a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables

I've created the following config file which contains parameters to be used by a batch file:

File *winscp.conf*:

```
folder    %appData%\winscp
version   5.7.4
visit     http://sourceforge.net/projects/winscp/files/WinSCP/
download  http://sourceforge.net/projects/winscp/files/WinSCP/5.7.4/winscp574.zip
```

Batch file (*get.bat*):

```
@echo off
setlocal

@if not exist "%1" (
    echo Config file not found in "%1"
    exit /B
)
@for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%A in (%1) do (
    set %%A=%%B
)

mkdir %folder%
```

When I call the batch file like this:

```
get.bat winscp.conf
```

I get a sub-folder *%appData%\winscp* created in the current folder, something like this:

```
c:\Temp\%appData%\winscp
```

While what I want is a *winscp* folder created in the Windows app data folder, something like this:

```
C:\Users\Caffe\AppData\Roaming\winscp
```

I think there's something wrong with the statement `set %%A=%%B`, since if I change it to `set %%A=%appData%\winscp` I do get the folder created the way I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables inside tokens should be expanded prior to the assignment by adding `call`:

```
call set %%A=%%B
```

Comment: BTW, if your values will ever have spaces here's a more reliable way to parse: `@for /f "tokens=1*" %%A in (%1) do`, %%A = the first word before space, %%B = the rest.

Answer (score 3):

I just summarize the answers of [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) and [JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz) with adding some small improvements.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
set "ConfigFile=%~1"

if "%ConfigFile%" == "" (
    echo %~nx0 must be called with name of configuration file
    echo as first parameter, for example: %~nx0 winscp.conf
    goto EndBatch
)

if not exist "%ConfigFile%" (
    echo Config file "%ConfigFile%" not found.
    goto EndBatch
)

set "folder="

for /F "usebackq tokens=1*" %%A in ("%ConfigFile%") do call set "%%A=%%B"

if "%folder%" == "" (
    echo Option "folder" not defined in config file "%ConfigFile%".
    goto EndBatch
)

mkdir "%folder%" 2>nul

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

For better reading what first argument passed to the batch file should be, the parameter is immediately assigned to an environment variable without the surrounding quotes which must be used if configuration file name with or without path contains anywhere at least 1 space character.

Next a check is made if batch file was called at all with a parameter.

After **FOR** loop it is verified if the configuration file really contained an entry for `folder`.

And creation of directory is made with using quotes because folder path can contain spaces, and with redirecting any error message to device **nul**, i.e. suppress the error message output if directory exists already.

Answer (score 1):

With next changes in your code:

- `call set` instead of `set`
- `for /f "tokens=1,*` instead of `for /f "tokens=1,2`

then next code snippet should work:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions
if not exist "%1" (
    echo Config file not found in "%1"
    exit /B
)
for /f "tokens=1,* delims= " %%A in (%1) do (
    call set "%%A=%%B"
)
mkdir %folder%
```